# Excel Nested Conditional If Formula with Binary 0 or 1 Output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use a multi-nested conditional Excel formula properly. I think what I have is close but I'm missing something.

```
=IF(BF6=1,IF(AI6=AI9,IF(BC8=0, 0,1)))
```

I am not sure I can use AI6=AI9 to specify that the contents of these cells are identical.

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Separately, I want this formula to repeat every 7 rows, so I expanded the formula to include the this function:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,7),"",IF(BF6=1,IF(AI6=AI9,IF(BC8=0, 0,1)))
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

[Screenshot of problem with new formula: =IF(AND(EXACT(AI6,AI9),BF6=1,BC8=0),1,0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CSUy.png)

[Image of final formulas that work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuHAz.png)

Answer (score 0):

**REVISED:**

[image]

From what I understand, this is what you want.  Copy the following formula and paste on `cell BB9` then drag the formula down to where the record ends.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-2,7),"",IF(AND(AI6=AI9,BH6=1,BH9=0),1,0))
```

`MOD(ROW()-2,7)` is to determine where the result should show.  `Row()` means the current row, and I subtract 2 to eliminate header row and blank row on row 2.  `7` is to repeat every 7 rows.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157526/discussion-on-answer-by-ian0411-excel-nested-conditional-if-formula-with-binary).

Comment: I think the last formula you gave me works, Ian. There were just some quirks to the blank spaces in my spreadsheet. You did a great job on this and I really appreciate all the time you spent on it. You are very knowledgable and patient. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to use two formulas in two consecutive cells to make it calculate correctly.

[image: screenshot of solution]

```
=IF(EXACT(AI6,AI9), 1,0)

=IF((AND(BB9=1, BF6=1, BF9=0)), 1, 0)
```

I will conquer using `IF`, `AND` and `EXACT` in one conditional formula some other time. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: `EXACT` works like `=` except it is case-sensitive.  So you can shorten your formula by doing `AI6=AI9` if you don't care about whether it is upper or lower cases.

Comment: I had it like this in my original formula above, and it didn't calculate correctly. I'll check it gain.Thanks.